# Trick to find if number is composite or prime

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-factorization

I was doing some maths and required a function which mimics the following function:

$$ f(k,c) = \mid \sin(k/2) \sin(k/3) ... \sin(k/c) \mid $$

So that I can evaluate (say $ f(k,3.5) $) or is there any other method by which I can take derivatives with respect to c (without knowing the proper f function)?

I think it would be unfair of me not to tell you the motivation:

Let's say we have a composite number: $ z = xy $

Where $ x<z^{1/2}<y<z $

Then if we evaluate $ f(z \pi ,x)=0 $ as $\sin(z\pi/x)=\sin(y\pi) =0$

So it is a matter of finding the zeros of $f$ which my instincts and a bit of graphing the function $f$ (with pen and paper) tell me will be at:

$$\partial f/\partial c=0$$

If the first zero lies on the number $z$ itself the number is prime else if $f$ becomes $0$ before that it is a composite.

P.S: If there is any clarification required feel free to comment

Comment: Just for clarification: The divisors in the argument of $\sin$ are just $2,3,4,5,6,...,c$ and not only the prime numbers?

Comment: Yes ... I thought that it might help somehow if we used $2,3,4, ...$ instead of prime numbers

Answer (score -2):

You can't take derivatives of this function with respect to $c$, because it's defined only for integer values of $c$.

Comment: Thats why I'm asking if there is a function which "mimics its behaviour" and happens to be continuous

Comment: I know taking the derivative of a discrete function is not possible but for example we can take a derivative of the gamma function which behaves like x!