# How to convert a discrete function to a continuous function

Tags: analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics

I was wondering because of this: [Trick to find if number is composite or prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082306/trick-to-find-if-number-is-composite-or-prime)

Is there any formal method to convert a discrete function to a continuous function. For example take $n!$, how was the gamma function discovered? Is there a general procedure to get the continuous function (which mimics a discrete function)?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481972/analytic-continuation-of-factorial-function/481985#481985

Comment: The general study of how to extend a discrete function to a continuous one is known as [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).  Note that the Gamma function is one of (infinitely) many continuous functions that mimic the behavior of the factorial over the integers.  However, the Gamma function is useful for its nice characteristics [besides continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), such as analyticity in the complex plane.

Comment: Can you use interpolation on this function? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082306/trick-to-find-if-number-is-composite-or-prime

Answer (score 2):

In general, there any many ways for extending a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$ in such a way that $g$ is a continuous function and $g_{|\mathbb{Z}}\equiv f$. For the $\Gamma$ function, the uniqueness of the extension follows from requiring that for any $z\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $g(z+1)=z\, g(z)$ (the same functional identity satisfied by $f$ on $\mathbb{N}$) and $\log g$ is a convex function: see the [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the discrete function is defined, there might be simple ways to extend it to a continuous function on $\mathbb R$, e.g. if $f: \mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ is defined as the constant $65$, it's quite obvious to consider the function that is constant $65$ on $\mathbb R$ as an extension, but $65\sin(\pi x)$ is also a choice.

In some cases the function has other properties that helps us choose, but different properties also means that there are no general way of finding a valuable extension.

If the function satifies a functional equation like $n! = n(n-1)!$ that can sometimes be used as a starting point for finding some functions that has matches the discrete function.